# checking a member of struct to be only alphabetic

Tags: c++

I tried to use,

```
if(isalpha(card[i].name))
...
```

but it says that i can't use it with char type here is my code:
This is the struct:

```
struct firm {
unsigned egn;
char name[80];
char lastname[80];
char department[80];
unsigned salary;
}card[100];
```

This is the function where i want to make the check if only letters then to continue:

```
void enter()
{
int i, n;
char temp[80];
do{
    cout<<"Enter how many workers you want to add: ";cin>>n;
}while(!(n>0 && n<101));
for(i=top;i<n;i++)
{/*ЕГН + проверка*/
    cout<<"Enter EGN: ";do{
    cin>>temp;
if((strlen(temp)!=10))
    cout<<"Enter EGN: ";
}while(strlen(temp)!=10);
card[i].egn = (unsigned) atoi (temp);
/*Име Фамилия*/
cout<<"Enter name(only letters): ";cin>>card[i].name;
cout<<"Enter lastname(only letters): ";cin>>card[i].lastname;
cout<<"Enter department: ";cin>>card[i].department;
cout<<"Enter salary: ";cin>>temp;
card[i].salary = (unsigned) atoi (temp);
}
}
```

When i try to use this kind of code:

```
cout<<"Enter name(only letters): ";do{
cin>>card[i].name;
if(isalpha(card[i].name))
.....;
```

and it says that i can't use char in int (isalpha uses int? )

Comment: The type of `name` is not `char`. You should pay more attention to the compiler's erro message. If you do, you will notice the type in question is `char[80]`, not `char`.

Comment: So as unwind says i need to make a loop for each digit ?? how can i do it

Answer (score 2):

You need to *loop* over every character of the string, `isalpha()` only tests a single character.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `isalpha` on an entire `char` array, only on individual characters. To check that every character in a `char` array is alphabetical, you can use the `std::all_of` algorithm:

```
auto name_begin = std::begin(card[i].name);
auto name_end = std::end(card[i].name);
bool name_alpha = std::all_of(name_begin, std::find(name_begin, name_end, '\0'), std::isalpha);
if (name_alpha) {
  std::cout << "It's alphabetical!" << std::endl;
}
```

If you're using a compiler without the necessary C++11 support, you can do:

```
char* name_begin = card[i].name;
bool name_alpha = std::all_of(name_begin, name_begin+std::strlen(name_begin), std::isalpha);
if (name_alpha) {
  std::cout << "It's alphabetical!" << std::endl;
}
```

Then the boring way without using the standard library algorithms:

```
bool name_alpha = true;
for (char* character = card[i].name; *character != '\0'; character++) {
  if (!std::isalpha(*character)) {
    name_alpha = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (name_alpha) {
  std::cout << "It's alphabetical!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i cannot understand the meaning of that code - can you please make it in my code (i tried to put it right after my code but here are some errors that i can't understand too) Thanks

Comment: Chances are you don't have C++11 support or you haven't enabled it. Try the edit. Make sure you have `<algorithm>` and `<cctype>` included.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that name is itself an array of chars, so you need to test each each element something like this:

```
.....
cout<<"Enter name(only letters): ";do{
cin>>card[i].name;
bool bIsAlpha = true;
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(card[i].name); ++j)
{
  if(!isalpha(card[i].name[j]))
  {
    bIsAlpha = false;
    break;
  }
}
if (bIsAlpha)
{
  .....;
}
```

Comment: in that line "for (int j=0; j<strlen(name)... " name is identifier ... what i need to type in "if (bIsAlpha). Can you fix it a little bit please

Comment: I made a small change (replaced `strlen(name)` with `strlen(card[i].name)`.. But I'm not sure what you're asking?